# smtp callback on new email

Tags: php, smtp

I have a custom app that i built which relies on a cron job to check for new email every 5 minutes. If there is a new email it then performs an action. What I would like to do is have a callback fired off when a new email arrives and then perform the action.

I could set the cron job to 1min intervals ( currently it is set to 5min ) but this seems like a waste of resources. The app is built in php and any help would be appreciated, i am just not sure what direction i should be looking at them moment.

M

Comment: You can use a .forward to send an email directly to an app, which would remove the cron job requirement. But you'll have to provide more details of what this callback should do.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7028686/capture-and-manage-email-data-with-php/7028828#7028828 for some info on where to start. You can instruct your MTA (sendmail/postfix) to deliver messages into a pipe into a PHP script

Comment: pipe the new mail to a script, skip the cron job

Comment: thanks guys. @marcB the callback/script just checks the email for an attachment and saves it to the server ( part of the custom app )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

very basic mail pipe script:

```
 #!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
// read from stdin
$fd = fopen("php://stdin","r");
$email = "";
while ( !feof($fd) ){
    $email .= fread($fd,1024);
}
fclose($fd);

?>
```

what you do with $email, depends on what you need

Comment: for all that, might as well just do `$email = file_get_contents('php://stdin')`.

Comment: i removed the code from my script where a process the stream, but of course you are right. but its php there's a dozen ways to do anything

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like [MailGun](http://mailgun.net/) or SendGrid's [Parse API](http://sendgrid.com/documentation/display/api/Parse) which will receive your email for you and callback to an endpoint you specify.